# Light theme is showing for a second before dark theme is loaded

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I would like to ask for some help about this issue. I am not sure why, but I have a switch for dark theme. When dark theme is used and I try to load any other component, I can see the default light theme for a second before it switches to dark theme. I tried to use v-cloak with css, but nothing happens. I am not sure what to try anymore.

Thank you for any advices in advance.

```
<template>
  <div id="app" v-bind:class="{ darkMode: isDark }" v-cloak>
    <div class="upperBar">
      <a href="/"><img src="./assets/NewIconBlack.png" id="logo"></a>
      <Logo msg="MEETINK"/>
      <Nav />
    </div>
    <router-view />
    <div class="login_register">
      <Login />
      <Register />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Logo from './components/Logo.vue'
import Login from './components/Login.vue'
import Register from './components/Register.vue'
import Nav from './components/Nav.vue'
import firebase from 'firebase'  
require('firebase/auth')
import db from './main'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Logo,
    Login,
    Register,
    Nav
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isDark: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
       firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
                if(user){
                     const modeRef = db.collection('modes');
                    /*modeRef.doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get().then(doc => {
                            if(doc.data().backgroundMode === 'dark'){
                              this.isDark = true
                            }else {
                              this.isDark = false
                            }
                    })*/
                    modeRef.doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
                            if(querySnapshot.data().backgroundMode === 'dark'){
                              this.isDark = true
                            }else {
                              this.isDark = false
                            }
                    })
                }else {
                    this.$router.push('/')
                }
            })
  }
}
</script>

<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.login_register{
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

[v-cloak] { 
  display: none!important; 
}

#logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
}

.upperBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 20px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 20px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.darkMode {
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 20px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 20px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  color: rgb(105, 126, 147)!important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The effect is caused by rendering the component first and adding the reactive class afterwards. Have you thought about using the `data-theme="dark"` attribute? There are many articles on this, for instance [this one](https://dev.to/wendell_adriel/working-with-multiple-css-themes-5aej).

Comment: It sounds interesting and I might try it later but I would like to try this. Can I add class to element before rendering the component?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a localStorage to set the value of theme and also add script tag without src, inside the top of the body, which toggles the dark theme.

Something like this,

```
<script>
  if(localStorage.getItem('darkMode') == 'enabled'){
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme');
  }
</script>
```